# Reading variable from input text and opening in a new tab without posting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I would like to read a search term from an input text and when I click a link on the page, I would like to append this search term to the link and open in new page

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("a.mylink")[0] ;
a.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var query = e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.textContent;
    window.open(e.currentTarget.href+"?"+query,"_blank");
},false);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search_term">
<a target="_blank" class="mylink" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Preview Search Results</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/bvr5jmas/1/

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
a.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var query = e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.value;
    window.open(e.currentTarget.href+"?"+query,"_blank");
},false);
```

For multiple a tag concept:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/bvr5jmas/3/

For single a tag and a corresponding input:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="search_term" data-for="someLink">
<a target="_blank" id="someLink" class="mylink" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Preview Search Results</a>
```

JS:

```
var aTag = document.querySelector("a.mylink") ;
aTag.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var query = document.querySelector("input[data-for='"+e.currentTarget.id+"']").value;
  window.open(e.currentTarget.href+"?"+query,"_blank");
},false);
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/bvr5jmas/6/

Comment: Let's pretend that my link has a class of "mylink". So how will I relate the link with this input?

Comment: replace elemByTagName with document.querySelectorAll("a.mylink")[0]. I am also assuming that the input is the previous sibling of the link. So you need to change that too. Or it would be much better if you specify each other either by name attribute or the data-attributes

Comment: Can you please check my code snippet? I tried and didn't work.

Comment: Rather than     var query = e.currentTarget.previousElementSibling.value; is there a better way like catching from id class etc? Because since this is an example there are not a lot of elements.

Comment: Of course why not. But I do not know what attributes or classes you will have on your input so gave this example based on what you post. But for instance if you had a data-for="xyz" attribute on your input and your a tag has an id of "xyz", I could have done `document.querySelector("input[data-for='"+e.currentTarget.id+"']")` within the handler, or something like this.

Comment: If possible can you please update jsfiddle with this assumption so that I cano just apply right away_?

Comment: Yes this is fine with extras. Actually I don't need multiple tag. 1 input and 1 link was more than enough. I just deleted array from aTags and I think it works. It would be great if you could just simply it to make it work for 1 input. But anyway this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a keyup listener on search_term, and update your link href when the search term changes

```
$(function() {
  $('#search_term').keyup(function() {
    var link = $(this).next("a").get(0);
    link.href = "xyz.com/" + this.value;
  });
});
```

Comment: Let's pretend that my link has a class of "mylink". So how will I relate the link with this input?

Comment: I don't really get your question, but it seems like you want some selector for class "mylink", or?

Comment: Please check my code snippet. I added an example. So that what I want is when I type something, it needs to append the search term to the link ( on the fly or on click)